# How to extend jQuery from CDN?

Tags: javascript, webforms

I'm currently using a jQuery resides on my own FTP together with other web files. I am thinking of using a jQuery from CDN since suggested by the YSlow. The question is, how can I extend that jQuery? Or in other words, how can I add custom functions to it? I don't think I can edit that? Ha-ha! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a separate file with your own functions in it.

Any extension to jQuery should probably be done through its own [plug-in mechanism](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: Thanks! I should have checked jQuery website!

Answer (score 1):

Whether the jQuery library comes from your own server or a CDN, you'll add new functions in the same way.

```
jQuery.fn.yourCustomFunction = function(){};
```

This will be done inside your own Javascript files and you should never be editing the actual jQuery library file.